# Passing Data Between Different CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to pass data from a FeedCollectionViewCell to another ChatViewController.

**Inside Feed View Controller**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedCollectionViewCell
cell.postTextView.text = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].caption
cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "photoplaceholder.jpg")
cell.priceTextView.text = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].price
cell.categoryTextView.text = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].category
cell.usernameLabel.text = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].username
cell.buttonEvents = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
    let chatViewController =
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chat")
    self.present(chatViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
    var receiverIDNumber = cell.usernameLabel.text
}
```

//I want to Pass receiverIDNumber to ChatViewController

Inside ChatViewController:

```
    func sendDataToDatabase(message: String){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    **//I want receiverIDNumber to be the data that is passed from  FeedViewController**
    let receiverIDNumber = "21"
    let postsReference = ref.child("chats")
    let newPostId = postsReference.childByAutoId().key
    let newPostReference = postsReference.child(newPostId)
    newPostReference.setValue(["message" : messageText.text!, "senderID" : senderIDNumber, "receiverID" : receiverIDNumber], withCompletionBlock: {
        (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
    })
}
```

I am trying to get the receiverIDNumber (the user who will receive the message) from the FeedCollectionViewCell

For the cell.buttonEvents in MainViewController, it is to open ChatViewController.

The model for Main is shown below:

```
class Post{
var caption: String
var photoUrl: String
var price: String
var category: String
var username: String
var pic: String
init(captionText: String, photoUrlString: String, priceText: String, categoryText: String, usernameLabel: String, profileImageURL: String){
    caption = captionText
    photoUrl = photoUrlString
    price = priceText
    category = categoryText
    username = usernameLabel
    pic = profileImageURL
}
```

For eg in a cell, there is a button beside the userprofileimage that people can click on to chat with the users.Upon clicking the button, it will direct them to ChatViewController.In ChatViewController,i used a different model:

```
class Chat {
var message: String
var senderID: String
var receiverID: String

init(messageTextString: String, senderIDNumber: String, receiverIDNumber: String){
    message = messageTextString
    senderID = senderIDNumber
    receiverID = receiverIDNumber
}
```

As the receiverIDNumber(receiverUsername) is from the ChatCollectionView,i find difficulty reconciling it to username from the Main.

Comment: That’s the least of your problems with this code

Comment: @malhal It is just a portion of the code,would it better if i past the whole chunk in?

Comment: No examine the master detail app template and learn about prepareForSegue

Comment: And maybe don’t reverse sort the array of posts 4 times?

Comment: @malhal prepareForSegue is for passing between two view controllers?I am trying to pass data from a collectionviewcell to another collectionviewcell

Comment: But those cells are in different view controllers no?

Comment: The view controller passes data not the cells

Comment: @LioTan Collection view cells are for displaying data. They are not how you should get the data to send to another view controller. Your data model is for that - in this case that seems to be the array `posts`. As @malhal suggested, look at Apple’s example for master-detail app. The `prepareForSegue` method is exactly what you need.

Comment: I found this example app a useful way to learn. It uses a table view but the principles are the same for a collection view. It shows how to use `prepareForSegue`. You will see it uses an array to store the data and elements from it are what is shared between view controllers.

Comment: For example, the `receiverIDNumber` you need is the same as `posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].username` - you can add a variable in `ChatViewController` class and adding this after you instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a variable to your `ChatViewController` class:

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    var username: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Check if userID has been given a value
        if !username.isEmpty {
            // Do stuff here with username
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can assign a value to this after instantiating the view controller. I have put this in the `didSelectRow` method, so the new view controller will appear when a cell is selected. You still need to make each cell with `cellForItemAt` method.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
    let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chat")
    // Here is the important bit
    chatViewController.username = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].username
    // Present view controller
    self.present(chatViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
}
```

A few notes:

- Don’t put any actions, view controller presentations etc in `cellForItemAt` method. The system calls it for every item every time the collection view is redrawn, so this would be chaos. It is **only** for setting up appearance of each cell.
- Make a new reversed array of posts, rather than reversing it every time you need it: `let reversedPosts = posts.reversed()`
- I’m not sure what you `buttonEvents` does. Is this a closure that is called when a button is pressed? That’s why I opted to present new view controller when a cell is selected.
- You can also do this with a custom storyboard segue and use the methods: `performSegue` to present the new view controller and `prepareForSegue` to send data to new view controller before it presents. This would be instead of `self.present()` etc.

Comment: Hi Chris, i have modified my question, can u have a look at it? Thanks a lot

Comment: I will have a look

Comment: @LioTan I can’t think how best to approach this. I see you have posted a variation on the question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50554153/8289095 - Have you got a useful answer yet?

Comment: Sadly i still couldn't figure out the answer.