# Accessing a variable inside a method and allowing it to be passed using segue to other view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedCollectionViewCell
cell.postTextView.text = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].caption
cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "photoplaceholder.jpg")
cell.priceTextView.text = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].price
cell.categoryTextView.text = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].category
cell.usernameLabel.text = posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].username
cell.buttonEvents = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
    let chatViewController =
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chat")
    self.present(chatViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
    var receiverIDNumber = cell.usernameLabel.text
}
```

I want to pass receiverIDNumber to another viewcontroller,however i am not able do as the variable is inside the method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let chatViewController = segue.destination as! ChatViewController


    chatViewController.receivedString = receiverIDNumber
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as `prepareForSegue` is only triggered with `performSegue` not `present`

```
let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chat") as! ChatViewController
chatViewController.receivedString = cell.usernameLabel.text
self.present(chatViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
```

Comment: For my ChatViewController
let receivedString = ""
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let yourNibName = UINib(nibName: "ChatCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(yourNibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        receiverIDNumber = receivedString
    }

I think something wrong with my above code,any advice?

Comment: What's your problem ? , Does **receivedString** is printed nil ??

Comment: Yes printed nil

Comment: **receivedString** should be declared as var not let

Comment: var receivedString = ""
    var receiverIDNumber = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let yourNibName = UINib(nibName: "ChatCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(yourNibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        receiverIDNumber = receivedString
        print(receiverIDNumber)

It is still printing nil

Comment: First is it nil or empty string , second may be **cell.usernameLabel.text** is empty try to print it before the present line

Comment: Yup cell.usernameLabel.text printed the username for the mainViewController, empty string when printed from chatViewController

Comment: Did you attached any segue from the cell to the chatVc , if so remove it

Comment: I did not attached any segue, i think the problem lies when i initialize thus returning an empty string. 
 var receivedString = ""
    var receiverIDNumber = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       ..
        receiverIDNumber = receivedString
        print(receiverIDNumber)

Comment: Solved,i close and open my project clean it when i woke up again and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add   `chatViewController.receivedString` before present like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
    let chatViewController =
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chat") as! ChatViewController
    chatViewController.receivedString = cell.usernameLabel.text
    self.present(chatViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
```